# Custom Class Member not Found in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, image-processing

with the help of a tutorial I created a custom class to crop an image to a square.

It looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ImageUtil: NSObject {

static func cropToSquare(image originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    (...)

    return image
}

}
```

When trying to use this function in my ViewController class, I get the the error: ImageUtil does not have a member named 'cropToSquare'.

```
let croppedImage: UIImage = ImageUtil().cropToSquare(image: image)
```

But obviously it is there. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Interestingly enough this works fine for me (I'm using Xcode v6.4) ...

Answer (score 1):

It is a class method, not an instance method - delete the () from after `ImageUtil` as this is creating an instance of your class

```
let croppedImage: UIImage = ImageUtil.cropToSquare(image: image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `cropToSquare` as a static method, but you're using it as an instance method instead:

```
ImageUtil().cropToSquare(image: image)
         ^^
```

Change that by removing the parenthesis:

```
ImageUtil.cropToSquare(image: image)
```